# Crystal Report - Display Count of differents Details on same line

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports, report

i have a question on Crystal Report, i have a query that return a list of name that a free slots in the morning and free slots in the afternoon. A person can have 1 or several free slots in the morning or afternoon. The query return something like that:

```
    NAME   |  HALFDAY
  Jean     |     1
  Jean     |     1
  Jean     |     2
 Martin    |     2
 Martin    |     2
 Martin    |     2
Francois   |     1
Francois   |     1
Francois   |     1
```

1 is for the morning, 2 is for the afternoon.
So, Jean have 2 free slots in the morning and one in the afternoon.
Martin has 3 free slots in the afternoon.

I would like my report looks like that:

```
Jean      2 / 1
Martin    0 / 3
Francois  3 / 0
```

But i don't know how to do that. Any ideas please?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First group by customer

Create multiple formulas like

```
If halfday=1
Then 1
Else 0




If halfday=2
Then 2
Else 0
```

Now take the count of every formula in group footer

Take saperate formula in group footer

Write below code

```
Databasefield.customernam & totext(count of formula1) & "/" & totext (count of formula 2) //so on
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but the last formula retuned the total line that the query return. The formula is:
{dtStatDay.customerName} & totext(count({@Morning})) & "/" & totext (count({@AfterNoon}))

Comment: If it worked for you.. you can accept as answer so that others can use